# Search element aphabetical

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

I'm coding a function to do an auto complete on a search element but when I search for a specific name the auto complete does not appear in an alphabetical order this is the code in my model and controller.

This is my model I have uncommented the order line cause it shows the drop down on select with nothing, but onclick you can see the id echoed back with no lable/name. Somecode like this gave me null values. eg

```
{

    public function getName($term)
    $select = $this ->select($term);  
      $select    ->where('name LIKE ?', '%'.$name)
                 ->order('name ASC')
      }            ->limit(0,20);

public function searchEnterprise($term)
        {
            $select = $this ->select()
                    ->where('name LIKE ?', $term . '%')
                    //->order('name')
                    ->limit(10);
            return $this->fetchAll($select);
        }
```

//Controller

```
public function acEnterpriseAction()
{
    $phrase = $this->getRequest()->getParam('phrase');
    $mdlEnt = new Model_Enterprise();
    $results = $mdlEnt->searchEnterprise($term);
    $arr_rtn = array();

        foreach($results as $result)
        {

            $myarr = array( 'label' => $result->name,
                            'value'    => $result->id,
                            'id' => $result->id                             

                            );
            array_push($arr_rtn, $myarr);
        }   
    echo Zend_Json::encode($arr_rtn);
}
```

Comment: You need a orderby to make it aphabetical in your search query

Comment: Try to debug the $arr_rtn in your controller and check the array values.

Comment: its not returning name when I use order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to order the json by name:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $myarr[$result->name] = array('label' => $result->name,
                                  'value' => $result->id,
                                  'id'    => $result->id                             
                                  );
}   
ksort($myarr);

foreach($myarr as $name => $arr){
    array_push($arr_rtn, $arr);
}

echo Zend_Json::encode($arr_rtn);
```

and call `searchEnterprise` with the good parameter

```
$results = $mdlEnt->searchEnterprise($phrase);
```

Comment: Drop down appears but with no results to hover over

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Is your Json is OK?

Comment: here is my javascript....$( "#name" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
             $.ajax({url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/admin/ajax/ac-enterprise/phrase/'  + request.term,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){response(data);}})},
            minLength:2});

Comment: copy and paste it to see it well

Comment: you have not answered. Is your JSON is OK? ->var_dump()

Comment: yes it is. I'm getting results now with your code above but the dropdown its in alphabethical order when I try to look for an F letter it always starts at A, its the ksort in this case and does not want to use the oderby in my model query

Comment: I edit my answer. you don't call searchEnterprise with the good parameter.

Comment: Got it that was the problem it works perfect now. Thanks doydoy, which book do you recommend if I want to speed up my skills on zend, and should I be learning zend 2? and do you recommend yii or zend?

Comment: I don't know yii. and for your career, it's a good idea to learn Zf2. ;) for the book, i don't know english book. sorry. ;)

Comment: any book its ohk I will find a translator or english version

Comment: I have one but it is getting old. This is [_"Les Cahiers du Programmeur - Zend Framework"_](http://www.eyrolles.com/Informatique/Livre/zend-framework-9782212123920), but I think there is other good book about Zend. and if you begin in ZF2, there are better books. (but i haven't) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I give the link for auto complete in Jquery, you can refer Jquery and make some changes to Java Script.
[Jquery autocomplete example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)